# Is there a way to evaluate multiple columns and then the resulting rows with an array formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheet of renewal opportunities and the date that each opportunity move into a new renewal stage, which can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ktl0HykIvNUvleWJzVKk4qMNjkd7nNKkdmbiahxwRhI/edit?usp=sharing). The end goal is to see how many opportunities were in each stage during any given "snapshot date".

I created an INDEX MATCH formula that looks at columns of stage change dates and will return the stage based on the snapshot date given. The problem is that I have to have an additional column for each snapshot date that I want to look at.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$G$1," (AUTOMATIC)",""),MATCH(I$1,ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A2:$G2="","",TO_DATE(INT($A2:$G2)))),1)),"Untouched")
```

Is there a way to evaluate the columns with the INDEX MATCH formula and then the resulting rows, all in one array formula? I want the output to look like the table in Columns O:T.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(I2:M="",,"♠"&TO_TEXT(I1:M1)&"♦"&I2:M&"♦"),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦"), 
 "select Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col1"))
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(A2:G="",,"♠"&TO_TEXT(A2:G)&"♦"&REGEXEXTRACT(A1:G1, "(.+) \(")&"♦"),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦"), 
 "select Col2,count(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col1"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: The goal is to not have to use the helper Columns I to M at all and just use the stage change Columns A to G.

Comment: I still need to use the INDEX MATCH formulas created in Columns I:M because it gives me the stage for every opportunity at that snapshot date and then count all those stages in one array formula. The table that you show only shows when there is a stage change on that exact snapshot date, not where each opp is on that date.

Comment: Of course! If you take a look at the formula in cell I2, it uses an array formula with an index match to evaluate Columns A to G of row 2 to determine what stage the opp was in during the snapshot date. The table in Columns O to T then counts the stages in the helper columns I to M. The end goal is to eliminate the helper columns. To do this, I would need an array formula that evaluates each column of with the INDEX MATCH and then uses a COUNTIFS to evaluates all of the rows in one formula.

Comment: getting close... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xmZJcWT1IfBooHA8lLWafFWv7jtZ2Qg43SBlkjrkE0o/edit#gid=0&range=O2

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1:H1&C2:C&"*",QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IF(Sheet1!A2:G="",,FLOOR(Sheet1!A2:G-2,7)+2&Sheet1!A1:G1&"|"),,9^99)),,9^99),"| ",0,0)),"select Col1,COUNT(Col1) group by Col1"),2,0)),COUNTA(C2:C),COUNTA(D1:1)))
```

and my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SZcAsALTxu2fpNu3s-4fIq-ms5IDyXijQWF1c49mtkU/edit?usp=sharing

I realize I don't have "untouched" figured out yet because i don't see any values in the "untouched" column, so i'm not entirely clear on the logic of that one yet.

How do the other numbers look?  I used FLOOR(...7 ) on the dates, so it'll count anything in the week associated with the monday, not just dates that fall ON that monday.